# How does the proof for the area law for 1D systems work?

Tags: condensed-matter, quantum-information, quantum-entanglement, spin-chains, tensor-network

I am currently reading this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1011.3445) in order to understand the proof of the area law for one dimensional, low energy systems such as 1D spin chains. The main area law theorem is given on page 13 and is called Theorem 5.1. In order to prove the theorem, the authors state and prove two lemmas. The first of these lemmas is proved in the paper by using contradiction. Following the contradiction, the authors were able to show that

$$S(2\ell) \le 2S(\ell) - \frac{\delta}{2}\ell + 1
\tag{1}
$$

Assuming that $\ell = 2^n$ for some whole number $n$, the authors claim that one can recursively apply the above inequality to show that

$$
S(\ell) \le \ell \ln d - \frac{\delta}{2}\ell \log_2\ell + \ell
\tag{2}
$$

However, I did not obtain the inequality $S(\ell) \le \ell \ln d - \frac{\delta}{2}\ell \log_2\ell + \ell$. In fact, I got the following:

$$
S(2^{n+1}) \le 2^{n+1} \ln d - (n + 1)\delta 2^{n - 1} + \sum_{m = 0}^n 2^m = 2^{n+1} \ln d - \log_2(2^{n+1})\delta 2^{n - 1} + 2^{n+1} - 1
\tag{4}
$$, or

$$
S(\ell') \le \ell' \ln d - \frac{\ell'}{4}\delta \log_2 \ell' + \ell' - 1 \le \ell' \ln d - \frac{\ell'}{4}\delta \log_2 \ell' + \ell'
\tag{5}
$$

**How does one go from equation (1) to equation (2)? Please kindly let me know.**

Comment: Can you boil down the question to the part where you get a different result than the paper (i.e.: same starting point, different outcomes), rather than the contradictions which can or cannot be subsequently derived from it? While this is important, it is of no use for someone who is trying to spot a potential mistake in your reasoning. (And it is not that the question wouldn't be technical enough without that extra information.)

Comment: @NorbertSchuch The paper found that the authors then state that if $S(\ell) < 0$, then $\frac{\delta}{2}\ell \log_2\ell > \ell (\ln d + 1)$ while I found that if $S(\ell) < 0$, then $\frac{\delta}{4}\ell \log_2\ell > \ell (\ln d + 1)$

Comment: I think it could make the question more clear if you added equation numbers, and used them to explain in your text what follows from what. I have added these equations for the purpose of the subsequent comment.

Comment: If I understand correctly the paper derives (2) from (1), while you derive (4) (or (5)) from (1). (2) gives a contradiction, (5) doesn't. But this doesn't mean there is no contradiction, but you just might fail to derive it. Thus, the real question to me seems to be how you obtain (2), rather than (5). The rest seems unnecessary. Unless, of course, you made the logical fallacy that if you don't derive a contradiction there is none.

Comment: On a different note, a more humble title might be in order. It is unlikely that you found a mistake in the proof (though, of course, not impossible); it is much more likely that you made  a mistake somewhere.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I changed the title. Yes, my question is how to obtain (2). I am not so sure why (2) is true. Why does (2) work?

Comment: In that case, wouldn't it be better if you remove all the unnecessary parts from the question and just ask why (1) implies (2)?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I removed the extra parts of the post.

Comment: I'm still confused. If you want to know how to get from (1) to (2), you can stop there. If you want to find the mistake in your derivation, you have to point out what you did to get there.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Basically, I started from equation (1) and replaced $\ell$ with $2^n$. This transformed (1) into $S(2^{n+1}) \le 2S(2^{n}) - \frac{\delta}{2}2^{n} + 1$. Then we see that $S(2^{n+1}) \le 2[2S(2^{n-1}) - \frac{\delta}{2}2^{n-1} + 1] - \frac{\delta}{2}2^{n} + 1$.  I repeated this recursion a couple of times and I got the above. Then, to make sure that my answer seemed ok, I choose specfic values of $n$, plugged it into the formula I derived and compared with with brute force applications of equation (1) to check whether my derived formula agreed with brute force.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch As you can see, my goal while reading this part of the paper was to practice rederiving equation (2) from (1). Based on the result I derived (equations (4) and (5)) I was not able to reproduce the results. Therefore I want to know how (2) follows from (1), which is basically the same thing as asking where did I make a mistake in my derivations. Knowing my mistake in my derivations will help me understand how to go from (1) to (2), and knowing how to go from (1) to (2) will help me understand what mistake, conceptual or mathematical, I made in my own attempted derivations.

Comment: Well, but "please find the mistake in my derivation" is a different question than "how do I get (2) from (1)". Also, your derivation seems unclear.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch OK, I see. I removed the phrase "please find the mistake in my derivation."